# Java Sandbox Model: ist the ClassLoader sufficient?

Tags: web-application, java, sandbox

I am creating a web application that runs untrusted code written by the user in Java. Of course the code is not supposed to have access to anything I don't want it to, so I wanted to implement the Java Sandbox Model. As a part of the Sandbox is the ClassLoader architecture, I wrote a custom ClassLoader to load the class, that contains the untrusted code and as far as I understood, that particular ClassLoader will then try to load every class that is used in the loaded class. I created a whitelist of packages and classes from the Java API that the code can access and whenever it tries to load something else, the custom ClassLoader is going to refuse loading.

Is it necessary for me to specify a Security Manager to complete the Sandbox or is this kind of architecture alone safe and adding a Security Manager would be redundant?